# Global var not working

Tags: javascript, global-variables

When I try the code is says "undefined" for the key variable. I think it somehow isn't global even though I didn't put it in a function. 
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27 + 96);

function lespres(event) {

    var p = 0;
    document.getElementById('pedonummer').innerHTML = "random getal" + key;
    var x = event.which;
    document.getElementById('teest').innerHTML = "KEY PRESSED: " + x;
    if(x == key) {
        var p = p + 1;
        document.getElementById('punten').innerHTML = p + "points";
        var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27 + 96);
    }
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared, using `var`, two variables named `key`.

The one defined after `<script>` is masked, inside the function, by the one defined after `document.getElementById('punten').innerHTML = p + "points";`

Comment: thanks! but still have a problem; generating a new "key" when the key I pressed is correct (so the same as the var key)

Answer (score 0):

You have it double defined. One globally and the other locally.

You have to remove the `var` keyword from the local one.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27 + 96);

function lespres(event) {

    var p = 0;
    document.getElementById('pedonummer').innerHTML = "random getal" + key;
    var x = event.which;
    document.getElementById('teest').innerHTML = "KEY PRESSED: " + x;
    if(x == key) {
        var p = p + 1;
        document.getElementById('punten').innerHTML = p + "points";
        key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27 + 96); // HERE
    }
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: that is indeed the error. But what if I want a new random number (key) if the key I press equals the random key that was generated in the first place? (so after the "if (x == key) ") I tried to make a function for the generation of the var but that didnt work

Comment: @sirolf Read the answer carefully and check for code differences with your code. You've done it well, but simply you have to delete the `var` key inside your conditional.

Comment: @sirolf If you run the function a second time, the old random number will be thrown out and your variable will take on the value of a new random.